# Switching tab using the button

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there any way that you can go to the next bookmark with an additional button in the middle of such a fragment?
I want to addicted to load in the second tab depending on the button pressed in the first tab. And when you select this button to automatically move to the next tab.

[image]

EDIT:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Start tab1 = new Start();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Rectangle tab2a = new Rectangle();
                    return tab2a;
                case 2:
                    Parameters tab3 = new Parameters();
                    return tab3;
                case 3:
                    Loads tab4 = new Loads();
                    return tab4;
                case 4:
                    Results tab5 = new Results();
                    return tab5;
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "START";
                case 1:
                    return "CROSS";
                case 2:
                    return "PARAM";
                case 3:
                    return "LOADS";
                case 4:
                    return "RESULT";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Start extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_tab1, container, false);


        final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              System.out.println("Rectangle");

            }
        });

        final Button button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Circle");
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    };


    }
```

Comment: Are you are using ViewPager to set fragments?

Comment: Yes, Edited question

Comment: Use mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

Comment: I added a piece of code which have methods for the two buttons. Can it be those methods do?

Comment: where are you buttons on the screen?

Comment: It is a sample screen. Without the buttons, but I have two Buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `ViewPager` as public field

```
public ViewPager mViewPager;
```

then call this method in your fragment button clickListener

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: It works nicely with the transfer. Only an additional problem. I have two buttons. And depending on who is forced, I would like to load different content in the second tab.

Comment: @Bartek You can create an `interface` and call it on button clicklistener

Answer (score 0):

Simple call this api on your button click.

```
mViewpager.setCurrentItem(int index)//0 for first tab, 1 for second tab and 3 for third tab.
```

you need to switch viewpager with tab.

```
tabs.getTabAt(int index).select();
```